# GitLab webhook how to exclude some folder or files?

Tags: gitlab

Gitlab has a webhook function that can send `http request` to a remote system,
but it can only hook at project level. all the event happened, webhook will be triggered.

In the same project, `file A` was handled by developer, `file B` was handled by QA, by some reason the both files are need exist at the same folder.

Is there a solution for committed `file B` **WON'T** trigger webhook?
Or Is there a solution for make different `http request` at different committed?

Thanks.

Comment: Make Webhooks configurable on a per folder basis: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/20430

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. So far I haven't found a way of excluding web hook requests based on specific file diffs. My solution is a script that checks out the ref from the hook notification, checks which files have diff'ed and then exits early if the files in question aren't part of the diff. I'm using [GitPython](http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for this. This isn't the best solution, but it doesn't look like GitLab supports file-specific hooks.